# Фильтрация товаров из файла JSON по по трем различным фильтрам на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript

Здраствуйте, в JS я новичок, поэтому хотел бы попросить помощи в более опытных программистов. Что на данный момент у меня есть:
1) я сверстал фильтры :
а) фильтр по списку 
б) фильтр по чекбоксам 
в) фильтр по цене с ползунком и инпутами

2) есть файл json где хранятся четыре товары(объекты)
3) есть JS файл который выводит эти товары на страницу

Вот как сейчас это выглядит:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/d00c8e6e5d116f383e6488267eb0761d/1566815950/104418/1334636/Screenshot_4.jpg

Мне нужно чтобы в начале отображались все товары а уже когда я буду ставить галочки, прописывать цену или выбирать из списка категорию, отображались только выбранные товары.
Знаю в интернете полно готовых решений на jquery но в моем маленьком проекте должен быть чистый js.

А вот код того что есть:
HTML:

```
<div id="filters">
     <div class="country"><h2>Country</h2>
       <select id="country">
       <option value="hide">-- Country --</option>
       <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
       <option value="china">China</option>
       <option value="france">France</option>
       <option value="italy">Italy</option>   
       </select>     
     </div>

      <div class="size"><h2>Size</h2>
      <div id="myDropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn" value="S">S<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn" value="M"> M<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn" value="L"> L<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn" value="XL"> XL<br>
      </div>
      </div>

     <div class="price"><h2>Price</h2>
       <div class="price-input"><input class="input-text" type="text"  value="">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</div>
       <div class="price-input"><input class="input-text" type="text"  value="">&nbsp;usd&nbsp;</div>
       <button id="submitprice" type="submit">OK</button>
          <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="goods"></div>

<script>var sex = 'male'</script>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {               
  loadGoods();
});

function loadGoods() {
    $.getJSON('goods.json', function (data) {
        var out = '';
        for (var key in data){
            if (data[key]['sex'] != sex) { continue; } 
            out+='<div class="single-goods">';
            out+='<h3>'+data[key]['name']+'</h3>';
            out+='<img src="'+data[key].image+'">';
            out+='<p>Цена: '+data[key]['cost']+'</p>';
            out+='<button class="add-to-cart" data-art="'+key+'">Купить</button>';
            out+='</div>';
        }
         document.getElementById('goods').innerHTML = out; 
    });
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "Рубашка №1" : {
      "sex" : "male",
    "name" : "Рубашка №1",
    "cost" : 1000,
    "country" : "argentina",
    "image" : "http://i.piccy.info/i9/9921ed03bf45751d45447b15e78be751/1566814909/19890/1334636/1.jpg",
    "size": "S"
  },
  "Рубашка №2" : {
      "sex" : "male",
    "name" : "Рубашка №2",
    "cost" : 1200,
    "country" : "argentina",
    "image" : "http://i.piccy.info/i9/acc4df9b14e48a42d7cd353e923673e7/1566814962/22015/1334636/2.jpg",
    "size": "M"
  },
  "Рубашка №3" : {
      "sex" : "male",
    "name" : "Рубашка №3",
    "cost" : 1700,
    "country" : "argentina",
    "image" : "http://i.piccy.info/i9/174610be67bfea39f99c956885ae3786/1566815027/25896/1334636/3.jpg",
    "size": "L"
  },
"Рубашка №4" : {
    "sex" : "male",
    "name" : "Рубашка №4",
    "cost" : 2000,
    "country" : "argentina",
    "image" : "http://i.piccy.info/i9/e2e5c6cb274121b9898b7d45a085130f/1566815049/29582/1334636/4.jpg",
     "size": "XL"
  }
}
```

СSS:

```
#filters{
    width: 200px;
    height: 800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
}
.price-input{
    float:left;
}
.input-text{
    width: 50px;

}
.single-goods {
    width: 280px;
    height: 530px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: "но в моем маленьком проекте должен быть чистый js" $.getJSON - а это не считается? если ты уже jquery юзаешь не проще на нем сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал без цены, там по аналогии. [codepen](https://codepen.io/programmwriter/pen/jONyNLb?editors=1010)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) { 
  let options={country:"argentina",size:["S","M","L","XL"],price:3000}
  loadGoods(options);
  const countrySelect = document.querySelector("#country");
  countrySelect.addEventListener("change", function(e){  
    options.country = e.target.value;
    loadGoods(options);
  });
  const sizeCheckBox = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
  sizeCheckBox.forEach(chbx=>{
    chbx.addEventListener("change", function(e){
      let sizeArray = [];
      document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(chbx=>{
          chbx.checked === true? sizeArray.push(chbx.value):null;
      });
      options.size = sizeArray;
      loadGoods(options);
    });
  });  
});

function trueSize(sizeArr,size){
  for(let i =0; i<sizeArr.length;i++){
    if(sizeArr[i]===size)
      return true;
  }
 return false;
}

function loadGoods(opts) {
    $.getJSON('goods.json', function (data) {
        var out = '';
        for (var key in obj){  
        if (obj[key]['sex'] === "male" && obj[key]['country'] === opts.country  && trueSize(opts.size, obj[key]['size'])&& obj[key]['cost'] < opts.price){
        out+='<div class="single-goods">';
        out+='<h3>'+obj[key]['name']+'</h3>';
        out+='<img src="'+obj[key].image+'">';
        out+='<p>Цена: '+obj[key]['cost']+'</p>';
        out+='<button class="add-to-cart" data-art="'+key+'">Купить</button>';
        out+='</div>';
        }
    }
         document.getElementById('goods').innerHTML = out; 
    });
}
```